# Can't access object prop in ts type

Tags: typescript

I have a type that looks like this:

```
export type GetTeamsQuery = {
  __typename?: 'Query'
  Teams?: {
    __typename?: 'Teams'
    docs?: Array<{
      __typename?: 'Team'
      email: any
      fullName: string
      id?: string | null
      order: number
      phone: string
      role: string
      county?: Array<{ __typename?: 'County'; id?: string | null; name: string } | null> | null
      image?: {
        __typename?: 'Media'
        alt?: string | null
        caption?: string | null
        url?: string | null
        id?: string | null
      } | null
      link?: Array<{
        __typename?: 'Team_Links'
        id?: string | null
        username?: string | null
        social?: { __typename?: 'Social'; id?: string | null; name: string; url: string } | null
      } | null> | null
    } | null> | null
  } | null
}
```

I'm able to access the first nested prop by: `GetTeamsQuery[Teams]`, but I can't do `GetTeamsQuery[Teams].docs`? How can I access docs?

I tried this as well:

```
type Teams = GetTeamsQuery['Teams']
type Docs = Teams['docs']
```

TS error:

```
Property 'docs' does not exist on type '{ __typename?: "Teams" | undefined; docs?: ({ __typename?: "Team" | undefined; email: any; fullName: string; id?: string | null | undefined; order: number; phone: string; role: string; county?: ({ ...; } | null)[] | ... 1 more ... | undefined; image?: { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | undefined; link?: ({ ...; } | null)[]...'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Teams can potentially be undefined. Try `GetTeamsQuery[Teams]?.docs`

Comment: Optional chaining don't work here. You'll get ```',' expected.ts(1005)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it after reading this article:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-remove-null-and-undefined-from-type

Solution:

```
NonNullable<WithoutNullableKeys<NonNullable<GetTeamsQuery['Teams']>['docs']>>[0]
```

Comment: If your question is resolved, please "accept" one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access this property, `teams` must not be `undefined`, typescript throws you the error, because in the case that `teams` is undefined, theoretically you will not be able to access a property of an `undefined`

so if it would work

```
export type GetTeamsQuery = {
  Teams: {
    docs?: Array<{
      email: any;
      fullName: string;
      id?: string | null;
      order: number;
      phone: string;
      role: string;
      county?: Array<{
        id?: string | null;
        name: string;
      } | null> | null;
      image?: {
        alt?: string | null;
        caption?: string | null;
        url?: string | null;
        id?: string | null;
      } | null;
      link?: Array<{
        id?: string | null;
        username?: string | null;
        social?: {
          id?: string | null;
          name: string;
          url: string;
        } | null;
      } | null> | null;
    }> | null;
  };
};

type Docs = GetTeamsQuery["Teams"]["docs"];
```

Comment: Cheers! It works, but it's not an ideal solution as the types are automatically generated with graphql-code-generator. I would have to rewrite the types manually.

Comment: In that case, so that you can work smoothly, you could use.
`NonNullable<GetTeamsQuery["Teams"]>["docs"]`

Answer (score 1):

I narrowed it down to a minimal reproduction to explain:

```
type Foo = {
  bar?: {
    baz: number;
  };
};

type A = Foo["bar"];
type B = A["baz"]; // Error: Property 'baz' does not exist on type '{ baz: number; } | undefined'. ts(2339)
```

**Explanation:**

The top-level property has a union type, one or more parts of which *do not have the referenced property* (in this case, `undefined` does not have the property `baz`).
**In your case, `Teams` can be `undefined` or `null`, which means that it may have a value which does not have the `docs` property.**