# Use of indexed access types yields error in strict mode

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I use [GraphQL Code Generator](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/) to generate types from my GraphQL queries. One of those types is the following:

```
type FindAllFilmsQuery = {
  __typename?: 'Root';
  allFilms?: {
    __typename?: 'FilmsConnection';
    films?: Array<{
      __typename?: 'Film';
      id: string;
      title?: string | null;
    } | null> | null;
  } | null;
};
```

Now I would like to use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to do the following:

```
let film: FindAllFilmsQuery['allFilms']['films'][0];
```

But this yields an error:

```
TS2339: Property 'films' does not exist on type '{ __typename?: "FilmsConnection" | undefined; films?: ({ __typename?: "Film" | undefined; id: string; title?: string | null | undefined; } | null)[] | null | undefined; } | null | undefined'.
```

If I set `"strict": false` in my TSConfig everything works fine - no error. However, I would like to keep `strict` to `true`. Is there any solution/recommendation to fix this problem?

Comment: See my answer to a nearly identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73309947/15261914

Comment: It's because `allFilms` may be undefined or null, which obviously don't have the property `films`

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Thanks for your input! I think your linked question does answer my question. However, I accepted the answer below, the effort should be rewarded as well I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a *much* simpler case:

```
type A = { foo?: { bar: string } }
type B = A['foo']['bar']
// Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ bar: "baz"; } | undefined'.(2339)
```

See the problem now?

You can't index optional property like this because you can't index `undefined` with anything, and `undefined` is a possible value of an optional property.

---

What you *can* do is remove all the nullish possible types with `NonNullable<T>`.

```
type A = { foo?: { bar: string } }
type B = NonNullable<A['foo']>['bar'] // fine
```

However, your example is a few levels deep, so you may need to make things `NonNullable` multiple times.

```
let film: NonNullable<
  NonNullable<
    FindAllFilmsQuery['allFilms']
  >['films']
>[number]
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgOwCYEEA2b5oLYGcCKArhAE4hQC8UA3gFBRQD6jokCAhthAPwBcUAcgBKAexHABAbnpR2GLHj40ZDZqwgcuSgQtwBhEQgQQAxsDiGpKqADM4OXEpQkS7EAB46Db0xbgNnDz8OvbYVj4McEj8uMAkiADm0hFQ5sBoQVCx8QgJUAA+UAiEGMneAL4FRSVoAHxVxaUylYWNaNLl0rQZwLah-AByhgM17ABGGe5DCCMY45PwyOiYoQTEZADaAnIrDgIAurVbdnuHG8XYY6T7tLTqUCiUNLZiStRQY+wkwZ8AXgJQSrlO7+KAAISeQggAEdCHASBAkO4UEcBDYxActp8SAcgA)

Comment: Perfect. I was aware that `undefined` was a (or _the_) problem - though I was not able to fix it or to address it properly in my question. I also checked the utility types of TypeScript, but didn't pay attention to `NonNullable`. It works fine now. Thank you very much :)